# multipart request does not work in spring rest service

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, gridfs

I have no idea what mistake I am making while sending request to upload the file, please have a look and suggest.

**Multipart Filter Configuration in web.xml file**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**FileController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadQuestionImg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<FileMetadata> commonFileUpload(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) {

        FileMetadata fileInfo = null;
        HttpStatus statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                FileInfoService reqFile = createFileInfo(file, "");
                fileInfo = (FileMetadata) operations.store(file.getInputStream(), reqFile);
                statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Exception occured", e);
                statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Invalid request");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<FileMetadata>(fileInfo, statusCode);
    }
```

**Multipart Resolver (implemented in dispatcher servlet)**

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
</bean>
```

I am not able to send request using chrome rest plugin, It says :  **400 Bad Request**, I have checked the URL & Content type (multipart/form-data) & file in the attachment, every thing looks okay. Please suggest.

Comment: Isn't a multipart Resolver required, where you specify the limit also? I have that, and I don't see that in your code. I don't know gridfs, but in Spring, it is required. If you need the resolver code, lemme know.

Comment: Sorry, And yes I have a multipart resolver also, I forgot to add it, let me add it in the question.

Comment: Also put the JSP/JSF/HTML code which you have, from where you are uploading images. I will directly compare it with what I have and works to indicate you the difference. I dont have anything web.xml for Multipart for starters.

Comment: I don't have any HTML/JSP I am sending request through, Chrome Rest Client, Let me add the screen image for the same.

Comment: Sorry I just joined stackoverflow so I don't have much reputation to upload the image.

Comment: Upload on postimage.org and post the link as comment.

Comment: Here you go. http://postimg.org/image/e4xc9g42r/

Comment: Now you are confusing me, the URL in the screenshot is different that from of the controller mapping you have in your main post. also, you expect the param name to be image, in screenshot, you have param name as 'fileUpload'. Rectify these issues please.

Comment: Sorry about that here is the updated image link : http://s23.postimg.org/kew3lctuj/request_Snapshort.png

Comment: Can you try removing the contents multipart from your web.xml

Comment: web.xml is the entry point of all requests, how does an application will come to know weather it is a multipart request or some other request, anyway I tried removing it and got and exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?"

Comment: I don't know, I guess this is all help I can provide, as I dont even have anything in web.xml related to Multipart and it still works. My last recommendation would be to write a basic JSP for file upload and try it out. Good luck!!!

Comment: Thankyou for your advice, but I am writing middleware for both web & mobile application.